# checkout success page events magento

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I have just created one module after checkout success event in Magento.

> etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Tech_Paymentinfo>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Tech_Paymentinfo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <paymentinfo>
                <class>Tech_Paymentinfo_Helper</class>
            </paymentinfo>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <paymentinfo>
                <class>Tech_Paymentinfo_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>paymentinfo_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </paymentinfo>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
                <observers>
                    <sales_order_place_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
                        <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
                        <class>paymentinfo/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
                        <method>savePayment</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
                        <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
                    </sales_order_place_after_handler>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

And here is my Observer.php file

```
class Tech_Paymentinfo_Model_Observer
{
    public function savePayment(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
            //Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_success', array('user'=>$user));
            //$user = $observer->getEvent()->getUser();
            //$user->doSomething();
        }
}
```

Now I want my custom payment method data after order success.

Can any one help me to sort it out issue.

Comment: so what is the goal of your custom module ? I'm not sure if i understood fully you issue here

Comment: i want payment method name into gift message field in sales order in admin section.

Comment: Rakesh Thank you as per above code also working fine for me.
Now i want my payment method name update into Gift message field in sales order in admin.
Means if i have checkmo payment method so i have update this into Gift message field into admin.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151826)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151826)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way...

using create **event** this way..

```
<checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
                <observers>
                    <sales_order_place_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
                        <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
                        <class>paymentinfo/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
                        <method>savePayment</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
                        <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
                    </sales_order_place_after_handler>
                </observers>
</checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
```

and using **observer** get specific payment method like 
 i have get check method

```
public function savePayment(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
            $order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
            $incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();

            $order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

            $payment_method_code = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode(); //Fetch the payment method code from order

            if($payment_method_code == "checkmo"){
                // your logic
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working fine... :)