# Update gift message after order success in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

[gift message](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267266/checkout-success-page-events-magento/267281?noredirect=1#comment378636_267281)
this link working fine for me, Now I want to update my **Payment Method** Name into **Gift message field** in sales order in **admin** side area, that Means if I have **checkmo payment method** , then update this into **Gift message field** into admin **side area**.

Answer (score 1):

Please do below changes as per your code into the site.

```
if($payment_method_code == "xyz"){

            $paymentmethodvalue = $order->getPayment()->getCheckNo();

            $giftMessage = Mage::getModel('giftmessage/message'); 
            $giftMessage->setMessage($paymentmethodvalue); 
            $giftObj = $giftMessage->save(); 
            $order->setGiftMessageId($giftObj->getId()); 
            $order->save(); 
    }
```

Add this code into observer file you will save payment method data into Gift card option in admin,

Comment: Thank you @nikul. It's working fine for me.